# RAD Studio (C++ Builder) 10.2 Tokyo: Hide TListView Vertical ScrollBar

Tags: c++, listview, scrollbar, hide, rad-studio

I have RAD Studio (C++ Builder) 10.2 Tokyo, and I was wondering how to hide or remove the vertical scroll bar on the TListView component. I can't seem to find any function or property of the ListView to do with the scroll bar apart from ScrollTo(const int) and 'ScrollViewPos' which both have nothing to do with the visibility of the scroll bar. Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit: I can not use `ShowScrollBar(HWND_ * hWnd, int wBar, int bShow);` because the TListView does not have a window handle property.

Comment: `TListView` does have a handle property (as do all `TWinControl`s) according to http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/!!MEMBEROVERVIEW_ComCtrls_TListView.html

Comment: The reference in that link is from 2009. It seems that Embarcadero has updated the component library since then, as I couldn't find the 'WindowHandle' property in the ListView component. I tried to compile it with `ShowScrollBar(ListView->WindowHandle, SB_VERT, false);` but it gave me the error `[bcc32 Error] Main.cpp(220): E2316 'WindowHandle' is not a member of 'TListView'`.

Comment: They've removed `WindowHandle` and made the protected `Handle` public by the looks of it: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TListView_Properties

Comment: Thanks for the link. Still not working though. TListView seems to not have any handle properties at all. I tried `ListView->Handle` and got:
`[bcc32 Error] Main.cpp(224): E2316 'Handle' is not a member of 'TListView'`

Comment: are you using an FMX `TListView` http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FMX.ListView.TListView rather than a VCL one?

Comment: Yes, I was. It turns out that the FMX TListView does not have the 'Handle' property, but the VCL TListView does. I tried it in VCL and `ShowScrollBar();` worked perfectly. Thank you for drawing my attention to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was trying the `ShowScrollBar();` function on the FMX `TListView`, which does not have the 'Handle' property, but the VCL `TListView` does. I then tried it on the VCL `TListView` and `ShowScrollBar(ListView->Handle, SB_VERT, false);` worked perfectly.